# macro to take Capital letter from cell vba

Tags: excel, vba

Great day for All.
Can I convert this function to macro?
to be easier to control many files by just one click

```
Public Function CreateShortcut(ByVal StrVal As String) As String

    Dim i As Long, tVal As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "[A-Z&/.]"
        .Global = True
        With .Execute(StrVal)
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                tVal = tVal & .Item(i)
            Next i
        End With
    End With
    
    CreateShortcut = tVal

End Function
```

regards

Comment: Capital letter or ampersand (&) presumably. The easiest way (maybe the only way) is to write a [user defined function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f).

Comment: Although I did agree to answer your question, it does not currently meet the site's guidelines. Please refresh your knowledge on [ask] and take a look around [help]. I have voted to close as a result. People refusing to ask questions as required have been known to lose their asking privileges in the past.

Comment: You can do this with formulas or with a UDF. Formulas are simpler with Office 365, but can be done with earlier versions. Show your efforts and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been beneficial for you to provide your attempt in how you "tried to create a macro" so we could better align our ideas with yours, but nevertheless, this can be done using Regular Expressions or various other methods.

The below method does use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) to perform these matches.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CreateShortcut(ByVal StrVal As String) As String

    Dim i As Long, tVal As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "[A-Z&]"
        .Global = True
        With .Execute(StrVal)
            For i = 0 To .Count - 1
                tVal = tVal & .Item(i)
            Next i
        End With
    End With
    
    CreateShortcut = tVal

End Function
```

You would use the above function as you would any other worksheet function:

```
=CreateShortcut(B2)
```

You are welcome to change the name of the function if you'd like, or continue to use the one I used in the example of `CreateShortcut()`.

[image]

*<sup>I am fully aware of the typo in 'Enggnering&Department' in cell B4. This is how OP presented their data in the question and I chose to keep it for the sake of consistency</sup>*

> It is important to understand that this code does not provide basic data validation, such as **preventing duplicate matches** or **ensuring there's even a capital letter** in the string. This is something you will need to consider in your project

The RegEx pattern is pretty basic.

- The bracket `[...]` is a character class bracket. It's job is to match any class of characters one time. In this case, you are either trying to match any capital character `A-Z` or the ampersand `&`.
- We set the `.Global` property to `True` to match *every occurrence* of the pattern in your string, which we can therefor iterate through them with our `For i =`  method.